# CSS - Transition on border not working fine

Tags: css, css-transitions

The CSS code:

```
.css3_nudge ul li a {
   -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color, padding-left, border-right;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms, 400ms, 400ms, 400ms;
}

.css3_nudge ul li a:hover {
   background-color: #efefef;
   color: #333;
   padding-left: 50px;
   border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

The HTML code:

```
<div class="css3_nudge nudge">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Register">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The transition is working fine for all elements but border, it just appears at the end of 400ms, there is no effect on border.

What I'm trying to achieve is a effect like the new google gmail buttons.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: I'm not seeing animations on Gmail's buttons. Since they're known for doing A-B testing, it would probably be a good idea to get us an animation or video of what you're talking about.

Comment: When your cursor is over the button you'll see it....with the new theme

Comment: As I said, there are no animations, even on hover, in my version. Google's known to do A-B testing, which means that different people see different versions of a site, and the users don't even know the other exists. The company uses it for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a pretty simple fix. You just need a border to already exist before the hover effect. So just set the `border-right: 1px solid #fff;` like below:

```
.css3_nudge ul li a {
   -webkit-transition-property: color, background-color, padding-left, border-right;
   -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms, 400ms, 400ms, 400ms;
   border-right: 1px solid #fff; /* added property */
}
```

Then the transition is effectively just changing the colour of the border instead of creating a border.

Comment: Just wanted to add for anyone stumbling across this now, you're probably better setting the border colour to `transparent`, saves you having to worry about colour managing it, especially if it's on a shared style.

Comment: @NathanHornby: +1 for border transparent. Thanks.